# How send a message from eventhub to another eventhub?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I would like to send eventhub customer and then download it to sample data such as weather and send another eventhub. My code is not working properly. There is no error but the data are not sent to the database.

```
public Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
        {
                try
            {
                foreach (EventData message in messages)
                {
                        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes());
                        NewClient Client = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewClient>(data);
                    if (Client.City != null && Client.Street != null )
                    {

                        GoogleGeoApi GeoClient = new GoogleGeoApi();
                        GeoClient.SetCoordinates(Client.City, Client.Street);
                        WeatherApi WeatherApiobject = new WeatherApi();
                        WeatherApiobject.GetJson(GeoClient.convertlat, GeoClient.convertlng);
                        string weatherdata = WeatherApiobject.sendEvent;
                        SenderEvent NewSenderEvent = new SenderEvent();
                        NewSenderEvent.DataSender(weatherdata, ConstFile.WeatherEventHubName);
                        //StartH(ConstFile.WeatherEventHubName).Wait();
                    }

                    Interlocked.Increment(ref this.totalMessages);
                    this.LastMessageOffset = message.Offset;
                }

                if (this.IsClosed)
                {
                    this.IsReceivedMessageAfterClose = true;
                }

                if (this.checkpointStopWatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
                {
                    lock (this)
                    {
                        this.checkpointStopWatch.Reset();
                        return context.CheckpointAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} > Event Hub Exception: {1}", DateTime.Now, ex.Message);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```

I will add that my receiver eventhub looks like this:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Bus-Event-Hub-45f43fc3/view/SourceCode#content

Comment: What is this class `SenderEvent`, is that class responsible for sending the data to another `EventHub`? If so, please post that code.

Comment: Pasting the code below. SenderEvent is the same for both messages(client and weatherdata)

Comment: And does the app reach the line `eventhubclient.Send(data1);` of the pasted code without exceptions? And what process is listening to the second event hub?

Comment: I hope you are well understood. I do not have any exceptions. In the commentary below, I add code eventhub listening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stream Analytics to do this very easily! Your first Event Hub is an [input](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-define-inputs/) in Stream Analytics. Then you you can write a [query](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns/) against the stream (Select * from [Input1] ... this will get you everything). You can [output](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-define-outputs/) the stream back to another Event Hub.

Comment: This seems like the best way to accomplish! Very easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class SenderEvent
    {
        public void DataSender(string data, string eventhubname)
        {
            var eventhubclient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConstFile.eventHubConnectionString, eventhubname);       
            EventData data1 = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
            eventhubclient.Send(data1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static async Task StartHost(string eventHubName)
        {
            string eventProcessorHostName = "1";
            string storageConnectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", ConstFile.storageAccountName, ConstFile.storageAccountKey);
            host = new EventProcessorHost(
                eventProcessorHostName,
                eventHubName,
                ConstFile.ConsumerGroup,
                ConstFile.eventHubConnectionString,
                storageConnectionString, eventHubName.ToLowerInvariant());

            factory = new DemoEventProcessorFactory(eventProcessorHostName);

            try
            {
                var options = new EventProcessorOptions();
                options.ExceptionReceived += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Exception); };
                await host.RegisterEventProcessorFactoryAsync(factory);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} > Exception: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), exception.Message);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

1. if your event hub is low latency - you can use Event Hub trigger (azure
   function that will be run whenever an event hub receives a new
   event). In your azure func your use code like in [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send)
2. If you have lots of events - you may try azure stream
       analytics filter out your weather data and send it to different
       event hub. You build a pipe line like this:

   EventHub1 -> AzureStreamAnalytics -> EventHub2